# Difference between top and vm_stat commands

Tags: macos, terminal, memory

What's the difference in the results between these 2 commands?
I was expecting top > unused to the the same as vm_stat > free

```
$ top -l 1 -s 0 | grep PhysMem  
PhysMem: 4701M used (920M wired), **7586M unused.**
```

```
$ vm_stat | perl -ne '/page size of (\d+)/ and $size=$1; /Pages\s+([^:]+)[^\d]+(\d+)/ and printf("%-16s % 16.2f Mi\n", "$1:", $2 * $size / 1048576);'  
**free:                     5405.87 Mi**  
active:                   3154.22 Mi  
inactive:                  631.42 Mi  
speculative:              2177.16 Mi  
throttled:                   0.00 Mi  
wired down:                917.55 Mi  
purgeable:                 176.78 Mi  
copy-on-write:            1868.59 Mi  
zero filled:              5617.72 Mi  
reactivated:                 0.14 Mi  
purged:                      0.44 Mi  
stored in compressor:             0.00 Mi  
occupied by compressor:             0.00 Mi
```

Comment: The explanation of why they are different quickly gets quite technical. Are you a programmer? - If not, just rest assure that these two values are not supposed to be the same, and there's nothing wrong with your system.